# Knapsack algorithm optimization for trading items

Tags: algorithm, optimization, knapsack-problem

I'm trying to use the knapsack algorithm but I have a little twist.

Lets say I have my items and another person items.

each of his items have price and value,
and each of my items have price and profit i made if I will trade this item.

I want to find the best of my items I can trade (which will be the ones with the highest profit I made from trading them) and his highest profit items.

Where the price of his chosen items won't exceed the price of my chosen items.

Currently I'm solving this by creating all the combinations of my possible items, And using the knapsack algorithm on each combination.

At the end I calculate the profit I made from my items selling profit + his items profit and take the highest result.

The problem is that this is taking a very long time, and getting longer if I have more of my items and more of his items.

Any possible idea for solution?